strange face colors in edit mode
I'm repairing a 3d scan of a cat, to 3d print it eventually.
But since cats don't sit still there is a lot of repair work to do on the mesh.
While in edit mode I get these strange colors in the face, those faces are flat and the normals of the faces are OK so what causes this?
I don't want it, cause it confuses me during my mesh edits.


Hello maybe a problem of shading? Try Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data? Or please share your file

It was indeed clear custom split normal data... how on earth got that in the model ??
i have no idea, don't even know what it us used for.

I do now know what it is, but its unclear to me why my 3d scanner seams to set those
its just an obj import.

The split normals (the normals that determine the shading) are messed up (it can happen with imported FBX but I don't know the precise reason), to fix that go into the Data panel > Geometry Data > and click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data.
